# MongoDB aggregate return count of 0 if no documents

Tags: mongodb, count, aggregate

I have a MongoDB query that groups by 5min windows based on date and returns count (which is the total number of documents in that 5min window using `count: { $sum: 1 }`).

I'd like to have the query also return a count of 0 for a particular 5min window if no documents exist in that group. However currently, looks like only groups with a positive count are returned.

Current Query:

```
        const cursor = await collection.aggregate([
            { $sort : { time : 1 } },
            { 
                $match: {
                     $and: [ 
                        {selector: string },
                        {time: {$gte: timestamp }}
                     ]
                }
            },
            { 
                $group: {
                    _id: {
                        $subtract: [
                            { $subtract: [ "$time", 0 ] },
                            { $mod: [ 
                                { $subtract: [ "$time", 0 ] },
                                1000 * 60 * 5
                            ]}
                        ],
                    },
                    count: { $sum: 1 }
                }
            }
        ])
```

Expected response: timestamp with count of documents including sum 0

```
{ _id: 1525162000000, count: 314 }
{ _id: 1523144100000, count: 0 }
{ _id: 1512155500000, count: 54 }
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You'll have to create bogus documents in order for the grouping to pick them up which generally gets a bit nasty. That's something I'd do on the client side if possible. If you post some sample data and the expected result plus the existing aggregation pipeline we might be able to help you.

Comment: Not sure how creating bogus documents will help me figure out which 5min windows do not have documents. I have added my query and expected results. Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

Disclaimer: I do not recommend doing this on the server side (so inside MongoDB) but rather handle that case on the client side.

That said, here is a generic solution to your problem which should be easily adaptable to your specific case.

Imagine you have the following documents (or output from an aggregation pipeline as in your example):

```
{
    "category" : 1
}
{
    "category" : 1
}
// note the missing { category: 2 } document here
{
    "category" : 3
}
```

The following pipeline will create empty buckets (so documents with a count of 0 for the "gap" values that are missing from the range of values in the `category` field - in this case the number 2):

```
var bucketSize = 1;

db.getCollection('test').aggregate({
    $group: {
        _id: null, // throw all documents into the same bucket
        "min": { $min: "$category" }, // just to calculate the lowest
        "max": { $max: "$category" }, // and the highest "category" value 
        "docs": { $push: "$$ROOT" } // and also keep the root documents
    }
}, {
    $addFields: {
        "docs": { // modify the existing docs array - created in the previous stage
            $concatArrays: [ // by concatenating
                "$docs", // the existing docs array
                {
                    $map: { // with some other array that will be generated
                        input: {
                            $range: [ "$min", "$max", bucketSize ] // based on the min and max values and the bucket size
                        },
                        as: "this",
                        in: { // but represented not as a plain number but as a document that effectively creates a bogus document
                            "category": "$$this", // the bogus category will be set to the respective value
                            "bogus": 1 // marker that allows us not to count this document in the next stage and still get a bucket from $group
                        }
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}, {
    $unwind: "$docs" // flatten the "docs" array which will now contain the bogus documents, too
}, {
    $group: {
        _id: "$docs.category", // group by category
        "count": { // this is the result we are interested in
            $sum: { // which will be aggregated by calculating the sum for each document of
                $cond: [ // either 0 or 1 per document
                    { $eq: [ "$docs.bogus", 1 ] }, // depending on whether the document should count as a result or not
                    0,
                    1
                ]
            }
        }
    }
})
```

The output of the above query will be:

```
{
    "_id" : 2,
    "count" : 0.0 // this is what we wanted to achieve
}
{
    "_id" : 3,
    "count" : 1.0 // correct number of matches
}
{
    "_id" : 1,
    "count" : 2.0 // correct number of matches
}
```

Comment: playground: https://mongoplayground.net/p/spOKjh6iIZM

Comment: Could you share *why* you would not recommend doing this on the server side ? I'm facing the same problem and it fits my use case nicely (the query is in a config so there is no client language to use). Performance considerations ?

Comment: @VannTen, it's not primarily performance... It just feels like an overkill to run this rather complex query _assuming that there's another piece of client code_. So in your case there may not be an awful lot wrong running the query. But _if_ there was another layer available, the code required to pull off what's required here would arguably be easier to write and read in another language...